# Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, migration, angular-migration

[image]

```
Error: node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/packages/app/index.d.ts:17:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types' or its corresponding type declarations.

17 import { FirebaseNamespace } from '@firebase/app-types';
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth-types/index.d.ts:18:48 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types' or its corresponding type declarations.

18 import { FirebaseApp, FirebaseNamespace } from '@firebase/app-types';
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public.d.ts:10:10 - error TS2614: Module '"@firebase/app"' has no exported member 'FirebaseApp'. Did you mean to use 'import FirebaseApp from "@firebase/app"' instead?

10 import { FirebaseApp } from '@firebase/app';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/public.d.ts:6:10 - error TS2614: Module '"@firebase/app"' has no exported member 'FirebaseApp'. Did you mean to use 'import FirebaseApp from "@firebase/app"' instead?

6 import { FirebaseApp } from '@firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I got that error while upgrading project from angular 12 to 13.

```json
"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1"
"firebase": "^8.9.1",
```

I tried to reinstall previous version of firebase but still getting that error..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have only shown us an error.  No one can find what caused this error in your code without seeing the code.

Comment: I didn't write any code.I just upgrade the package